# Operation failed on file due to file permissions,hos_clientfileio.cxx 142

Tags: java, sap-iq

When i execute SQL "**LOAD TABLE ...USING CLIENT FILE...**" to Sybase IQ database in tomcat's apps,
get this problem"**Operation failed on file due to file permissions,hos_clientfileio.cxx 142**".

But when i run the piece code in a single java file (not under tomcat), the LOAD TABLE can 
succeeded.

what's the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries ,  i found the problems , i execute the following statement together.

1. set option allow_read_client_file='ON'
2. "LOAD TABLE ...USING CLIENT FILE..."

When execute them separatly, the poblem gone.